# Finished JS / HTML / CSS Code Conflicting with Wordpress WPBakery, Cannot Implement

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

With the help of codepen, I came up with the following :
https://codepen.io/Lancewalker/pen/zepjXr

You can see the mockup version here : https://i.gyazo.com/88a0d6815253cbca8981a276bb937673.png

It works perfectly and has the exact function I need, and the only thing missing is a mobile display which I have mocked up here:

http://www.lancewalkerdesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/LWD-FinalMockup.png

My problem : WPBakery is a nightmare. I bought this theme a long time ago which includes WPBakery and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to incorporate this codepen (or much of anything custom) into the site.

Plugins I have tried :
• Custom CSS / JS - Lets you add your own css (scss compatible) and javascript to the site
• Header Footer Code Manager - Lets you include scripts in your header without dealing with PHP.

I've tried using the custom HTML element and custom JS elements, including the scripts and html, and then adding the HTML into the stylesheet.

Here is the current working home page:
http://www.lancewalkerdesigns.com/

And here is what happens when I add the code using the custom html / js:
http://www.lancewalkerdesigns.com/home-page/

As you can see when you get to services, the little li elements on the right side of the screen which allow you to navigate from page to page end up randomly inserting themselves into the ul in the codepen I've created.

An uneducated guess : The JS used for the li element on the right side of the screen which allows you to navigate the homepage has conflicts with the JS / classes I've assigned to my codepen UL.

An alternate fix : If someone could help me rework the code to have the on click function without using lists / unordered lists and instead using custom classes there's a chance that it wouldn't conflict with Wordpress / WPbakery

If anyone can help, this is the only complicated thing I really want on the site but it's important to me. I'd be willing to grant access / pay someone to do this, I know it's just a matter of knowing how WPBakery / Wordpress works better than I do. I am pretty well versed in html / css but js / php I am a beginner at.

I would post this on upwork but last time I did that someone quoted me at 25 hours for the project, which even though I am not js / php handy, I knew was a massive overestimate.

```js
$(".tab_content").hide();
$(".tab_content:first").show();

$("ul.tabs li").click(function() {

  $(".tab_content").hide();
  var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
  $("#" + activeTab).fadeIn();

  $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");

  $(".tab_drawer_heading").removeClass("d_active");
  $(".tab_drawer_heading[rel^='" + activeTab + "']").addClass("d_active");

});
/* if in drawer mode */
$(".tab_drawer_heading").click(function() {

  $(".tab_content").hide();
  var d_activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
  $("#" + d_activeTab).fadeIn();

  $(".tab_drawer_heading").removeClass("d_active");
  $(this).addClass("d_active");

  $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
  $("ul.tabs li[rel^='" + d_activeTab + "']").addClass("active");
});

$('ul.tabs li').last().addClass("tab_last");
```

```css
/*************New CSS*/

ul.tabs li.active>img.img-inactive {
  display: none;
}

ul.tabs li.active>img.img-active {
  display: block;
}

ul.tabs li>img.img-active {
  display: none;
}


/**********New CSS*/

body {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}

h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

ul.tabs {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  height: 232px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul.tabs img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

ul.tabs li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  margin: 0 -20px;
  height: 232px;
  line-height: 31px;
  color: #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

ul.tabs li.active {
  color: #333;
  display: block;
}

.tab_container {
  padding-top: 75px;
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.tab_content {
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
}

.tab_drawer_heading {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .tabs {
    display: none;
  }
  .tab_drawer_heading {
    background-color: #ccc;
    color: #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid #333;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
  }
  .d_active {
    background-color: #666;
    color: #fff;
  }
}

#img2 {
  margin-top: 90px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs">
  <li class="active" rel="tab1">
    <img src="http://www.lancewalkerdesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Service1-Highlighted.png" class="img-active">
    <img src="http://www.lancewalkerdesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Service1-inactive.png" class="img-inactive">
  </li>
  </li>
  <li rel="tab2" id="img2">
    <img src="http://www.lancewalkerdesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Service2-Highlighted.png" class="img-active">
    <img src="http://www.lancewalkerdesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Service2-inactive.png" class="img-inactive"></li>
  <li rel="tab3">
    <img src="http://www.lancewalkerdesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Service3-Highlighted.png" class="img-active">
    <img src="http://www.lancewalkerdesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Service3-inactive.png" class="img-inactive"></li>
  <li rel="tab4" id="img2">
    <img src="http://www.lancewalkerdesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Service4-Highlighted.png" class="img-active">
    <img src="http://www.lancewalkerdesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Service-4inactive.png" class="img-inactive"></li>
  <li rel="tab5">
    <img src="http://www.lancewalkerdesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Service5-Highlighted.png" class="img-active">
    <img src="http://www.lancewalkerdesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Service5-inactive.png" class="img-inactive"></li>

</ul>

<div class="tab_container">
  <h3 class="d_active tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab1">Tab 1</h3>
  <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
    <h2>Tab 1 content</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac metus augue.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- #tab1 -->
  <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab2">Tab 2</h3>
  <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
    <h2>Tab 2 content</h2>
    <p>Nunc dui velit, scelerisque eu placerat volutpat, dapibus eu nisi. Vivamus eleifend vestibulum odio non vulputate.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- #tab2 -->
  <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab3">Tab 3</h3>
  <div id="tab3" class="tab_content">
    <h2>Tab 3 content</h2>
    <p>Nulla eleifend felis vitae velit tristique imperdiet. Etiam nec imperdiet elit. Pellentesque sem lorem, scelerisque sed facilisis sed, vestibulum sit amet eros.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- #tab3 -->
  <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab4">Tab 4</h3>
  <div id="tab4" class="tab_content">
    <h2>Tab 4 content</h2>
    <p>Integer ultrices lacus sit amet lorem viverra consequat. Vivamus lacinia interdum sapien non faucibus. Maecenas bibendum, lectus at ultrices viverra, elit magna egestas magna, a adipiscing mauris justo nec eros.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- #tab4 -->
  <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab5">Tab 5</h3>
  <div id="tab5" class="tab_content">
    <h2>Tab 5 content</h2>
    <p>Integer ultrices lacus sit amet lorem viverra consequat. Vivamus lacinia interdum sapien non faucibus. Maecenas bibendum, lectus at ultrices viverra, elit magna egestas magna, a adipiscing mauris justo nec eros.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- #tab5 -->
</div>
<!-- .tab_container -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

kindly remove the "$" sign and replace with "jQuery" also change the class names to something non-generic so that the code does not get any other style of the theme.

Comment: I think part of the problem is that there are generic class styling for any ul / li and possibly some javascript that targets them. In WPBakery, every element created goes inside a container that has a class and stylings pre-determined by wpbakery. So if I put a UL inside a wpbakery element, chances are somewhere in the css there's a style that targets any UL / LI that's held within the WPBakery container.

This is why I think a decent solution would be to try and replicate the code with no lists, just divs which have their own classes. I just don't have the knowledge to do this in JS